# How to non-interactively supply a passphrase to 'dmcrypt luksFormat'?

Tags: luks, dmcrypt

I'm writing a script which automatically sets up **testing environment** virtual machines. This script should automatically format a dmcrypt+LUKS partition for me, with a certain passphrase. Because this is a local testing environment I don't care about the security of the passphrase, I just want the entire VM setup process to be automated and non-interactive.

How can I non-interactively supply a passphrase to 'dmcrypt luksFormat'? I want to use passphrases, not keys, because in production we use passphrases for LUKS as well.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The first thing to do is to call the right command: it's `cryptsetup`, not `dmcrypt`.

```
cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/vda2
```

The second thing is that you can pass another argument to read the passphrase from a file, or from standard input (using `-`).

```
echo -n "This isn't a very secure passphrase." | cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/vda2 -
```

Note that the `-n` flag is necessary in `echo` to prevent a line feed from being appended to the password.

See the `cryptsetup` man page for other ways to pass the key material in.

Comment: I had some difficulty unlocking my volume after creating it this way. The newline character was tripping me up. `printf "This isn't a very secure passphrase." | cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/vda2 -` worked better for me. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

How to send passphrase with sudo

```
echo 'passphraze' | echo 'sudopass' | sudo -S cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda5 media -d -
```